# Pinch to Zoom image on mobile devices fabric.js

Tags: jquery, fabricjs

I am working on fabric.js and canvas. I upload an image I have zooming options by button it work well but i want pinch zooming on mobile devices.

Here is my working link.

[Cap Customizer](http://production.technology-architects.com/ADIL/cape_customizer_wp/customizer/)

I use different libraries but it not works for me.

Comment: Hi., Any advance?

Answer (score 3):

You can build a custom fabric library using http://fabricjs.com/build/. And functionality works by default.

In my case i select all options (`modules=ALL exclude=node`) and works.

You can test [this page](https://jsfiddle.net/gxoe83nb/) in your device and pich for zoom and rotate is enabled

Comment: Why node is exclude, I cant get that? can you tell me about this.?

Comment: in my case, i not need that, is the reason. But you can generate it with ALL including `node` and should be works perfect